# Why is a non admin user allowed to access my index page in Rails app? (Devise Gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using the Devise Gem to authenticate users.  Users create answers to a form in the app and only the admin is supposed to be able to view the results and also the index of all users filled in form. I have 2 users one has the admin attribute set to "true" and the other to "false" (previously "nil")

## Behaviour I expect

Only users whose admin attribute is set to "true" should be able to access the show and index views.

## What actually happens

When I only used the `authenticate_user!` method which is included in Devise it worked correctly in that users could only see the show and index pages if they were logged in. However when I added the authenticate method in order to only allow admin users to see the show and index pages all of a sudden every user could see them regardless of whether logged in or not. I do not understand why this behaviour is happening as now only logged in admin users should be able to see these pages, according to the logic in the code as far as I understand it. `current_user` is also a Devise Gem method.

I have the following code in my Formularios (forms) controller:

```
class FormulariosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_formulario, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate, only: [:show, :index]

  # GET /formularios
  # GET /formularios.json
  def index
    @formularios = Formulario.all
  end
.
.
.
.
.

 

  private

    def authenticate
      authenticate_user! && current_user.admin?
    end

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_formulario
      @formulario = Formulario.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def formulario_params
      params.require(:formulario).permit(:nombre, :fecha, :FdN, :direccion, :sexo, :email, :telefono, :movil, :profesion, :altura, :peso, :motivos, :especialistas, :dieta, :intolerancia, :detalles_1, :limites, :otro_1, :problema1, :p1, :p2, :p3, :problema2, :p4, :p5, :p6, :problema3, :p7, :p8, :p9, :problema4, :p10, :p11, :p12, :otro_2, :medicacion1, :m1, :m2, :m3, :m4, :m5, :m6, :medicacion2, :m7, :m8, :m9, :m10, :m11, :m12, :medicacion3, :m13, :m14, :m15, :m16, :m17, :m18, :otro_3, :suplemento1, :s1, :s2, :s3, :s4, :suplemento2, :s5, :s6, :s7, :s8, :suplemento3, :s9, :s10, :s11, :s12, :otro_4, :madre, :padre, :abuela_mat, :abuela_pat, :abuelo_mat, :abuelo_pat, :hermanos, :hermanas, :tios, :tias, :ninos, :sobrinos, :activa, :ejercicio1, :e1, :e2, :ejercicio2, :e3, :e4, :ejercicio3, :e5, :e6, :otro_5, :fumas1, :fumas2, :fumado, :alcol1, :alcol2, :alergia1, :alergia2, :habitos1, :habitos2, :habitos3, :habitos4, :galletas_tartas_bolleria, :leche, :huevos, :chocolates_dulces, :carne_roja, :carne_blanca, :pescado_blanco, :pezcado_azul, :carne_procesada, :pan, :te, :cafe, :refresco_lata, :agua, :verdura, :ensalada, :tick, :pecho, :dieta_sana, :motivacion, :desayuno1, :desayuno2, :desayuno3, :almuerzo, :almuerzo2, :almuerzo3, :cena1, :cena2, :cena3, :snacks1, :snacks2, :snacks3, :bebidas1, :bebidas2, :bebidas3)
    end
end
```

from schema.rb

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "admin"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

EDIT 1: User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Comment: Can you post User class, would like to check admin method

Comment: @srini do you mean the User model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it looks like you authenticate method does nothing but require user authentication.

You may prefer something like this:

```
class FormulariosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_formulario, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:show, :index]
  before_action :authenticate_admin, only: [:show, :index]

  # GET /formularios
  # GET /formularios.json
  def index
    @formularios = Formulario.all
  end
.
.
.
.
.



  private

    def authenticate_admin
      unless current_user.admin?
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    end

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_formulario
      @formulario = Formulario.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def formulario_params
      params.require(:formulario).permit(:nombre, :fecha, :FdN, :direccion, :sexo, :email, :telefono, :movil, :profesion, :altura, :peso, :motivos, :especialistas, :dieta, :intolerancia, :detalles_1, :limites, :otro_1, :problema1, :p1, :p2, :p3, :problema2, :p4, :p5, :p6, :problema3, :p7, :p8, :p9, :problema4, :p10, :p11, :p12, :otro_2, :medicacion1, :m1, :m2, :m3, :m4, :m5, :m6, :medicacion2, :m7, :m8, :m9, :m10, :m11, :m12, :medicacion3, :m13, :m14, :m15, :m16, :m17, :m18, :otro_3, :suplemento1, :s1, :s2, :s3, :s4, :suplemento2, :s5, :s6, :s7, :s8, :suplemento3, :s9, :s10, :s11, :s12, :otro_4, :madre, :padre, :abuela_mat, :abuela_pat, :abuelo_mat, :abuelo_pat, :hermanos, :hermanas, :tios, :tias, :ninos, :sobrinos, :activa, :ejercicio1, :e1, :e2, :ejercicio2, :e3, :e4, :ejercicio3, :e5, :e6, :otro_5, :fumas1, :fumas2, :fumado, :alcol1, :alcol2, :alergia1, :alergia2, :habitos1, :habitos2, :habitos3, :habitos4, :galletas_tartas_bolleria, :leche, :huevos, :chocolates_dulces, :carne_roja, :carne_blanca, :pescado_blanco, :pezcado_azul, :carne_procesada, :pan, :te, :cafe, :refresco_lata, :agua, :verdura, :ensalada, :tick, :pecho, :dieta_sana, :motivacion, :desayuno1, :desayuno2, :desayuno3, :almuerzo, :almuerzo2, :almuerzo3, :cena1, :cena2, :cena3, :snacks1, :snacks2, :snacks3, :bebidas1, :bebidas2, :bebidas3)
    end
end
```

Then if the user is not admin, he is redirected to root path of the app for show and index action.

EDIT

Actually I am not too sure of `authenticate_user! && current_user.admin?` is doing as it is not part of a `if else` statement. For sure it will need user authentication but I am not even sure what the second part even triggers.. if not an error.

(btw I am still beginner in Rails so I am not familiar will all kinds of Rails syntaxes)

Comment: This solves the problem. however I still dont see why my original code failed since if the current user were not an admin then the authenticate method would return false and therefore not render the page. could you explain why the original code failed?

Comment: Well this is my edit part explanation. You use `authenticate_user! && current_user.admin?` without including it into an `if else` or `unless else` statement so the app does not know what to do with it. It just get something like `true && false` or `true && true` and so ... ? My method authenticate_admin redirects to root if user is not an admin. This is not implicit in your original statement `authenticate_user! && current_user.admin?`. You have to be a bit more explicit. Devise is a bit magical because there is a lot of code behind. But if you set your own methods, you need be more specific.

Comment: Actually if `authenticate_user!` fails it will redirect you to Devise user login page and not leave you to see the controller action. Then if you have to create your own method for the admin login, you have to decide on a redirect page if it fails.

Comment: Also be careful to call `authenticate_user!` before `authenticate_admin` because `authenticate_admin` is using the Devise method `current_user` then you need be sure the user authentication is successful otherwise it can trigger some errors. As it is shown in my above code, the methods are called in the right sequence.